# Cannot write an xpath for a pseudo element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing

I need your help in trying to write the Xpath for a pseudo element in selenium.. I have attached the code snippet  below.

I need to write an xpath for the ::before element which is a check box and needs to be clicked?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Code:
[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geW1y.png)

I am trying to click on the check box.

Answer (score 0):

Use css (example with class = submitButton):

```
By.css(".submitButton::before")
```